# Check file modified within a timespan from a CSV list

Tags: file, powershell, robocopy

I have two question or a two part problem:

1. I have a CSV file with a list of files including full path, e.g.:

   ```
   C:\file1.txt
   C:\file2.xls
   C:\file3.doc
   etc.
   ```

   I need to check the modified date for each file and if its within a specific timespan, then output it to a new CSV file, e.g.:

   ```
   C:\file1.txt has modified time and date 01/01/2014 10:00
   C:\file2.xls has modified time and date 02/01/2014 12:00
   C:\file3.doc has modified time and date 03/01/2014 14:00
   C:\file4.ppt has modified time and date 04/01/2014 16:00
   ```

   Timespan = 02/01/2014 8:00 to 03/01/2014 20:00

   The `output.csv` file should contain:

   ```
   C:\file2.xls
   C:\file3.doc
   ```

   I've tried to modified existing PowerShell scripts I've found online, but honestly don't understand the code. I've tried using `foreach-object`:

   ```
   $names = get-content .\test.csv
   $names | foreach-object {(get-item $_.name).lastwritetime}
   ```

   but I'm falling over at job getting this to work.
2. I then need to pass the `output.csv` file to `robocopy`, which doesn't support it natively so might need to use a loop to call `robocopy`, to copy files from one location to another.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the solution below will not work if there are several files with the same file name. The only thing you'll need to add then is some form of source base address (from which the file structure is built) and a destination base address and just build the new destination path based on these.

```
$copyChangesSince = Get-Date "2014-01-08"
$doNotCopyChangesNewerThan = Get-Date "2014-02-02"
get-content .\files.txt | Foreach {
        Get-Item $_
    } |
    Where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $copyChangesSince -AND $_.LastWriteTime -lt $doNotCopyChangesNewerThan } |
    Select FullName, Name |
    Export-Csv C:\temp\filelist.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Since you only want to copy a single item at a time I'm not sure I see the benefit of using robocopy. In my example below, I've just used Copy-Item. If you really want to use robocopy it shouldn't be hard to replace that call with a call to robocopy.

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\filelist.csv |
    Foreach { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\temp\output\$($_.Name)" }
```

If you don't want to actually use the .csv-file afterwards, you could just as easily skip that part and replace the `Select` and `Export-Csv` with the `Foreach` statement from the Import-part (and of course skip the `Import-Csv` as well).

*Edit: Split the process into two parts, as was requested in the question.*

Comment: I'm testing the first section, its taking a bit of time. I'm not sure I understand why it won't work if there is more than one file with the same name, at least while the script is running its giving me a list with the full path.
Secondly the reason for using robocopy is because I need to keep the folder structure for every file that is copied over.

Comment: The first section will work just fine, even if multiple files have the same name. The second section, however, currently copies all files into the same destination folder, no matter the folder structure. For example; if you have a file c:\files\myfile.txt and c:\files\subfolder\myfile.txt then both would get the same destination path, i.e. C:\temp\output\myfile.txt. If you need to keep the folder structure, it should be pretty easy to adapt the above script to keep the folder structure (either using robocopy or copy-item for the actual file copy operation).

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, I had to make a copy of changes to my source file, it was a csv file and some of the file names has a comma, so I changed it to a txt file. I also had to remove double quotes from some rows, I'm guessing because of specific characters in the file name.
I'll tweak the second part as suggested and try and use copy-item.